# Variable parameters in cosmology

Tags: cosmology, physical-constants

Mainstream theories in cosmology assume that parameters like the speed of light $c$, and the gravitational constant $G$ are time-independent. Is there any evidence suggesting that this assumption is reasonable, and what would the implications be if $c$ or $G$ were time-dependent?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21721/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144262/2451 , and links therein.

Comment: Its not a duplicate. That question asks whether parameters can be location-dependant.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou . . . or time-dependent.